# Is there a way to automatically tie a UITextField to a variable in my data model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uitextfield

I'm building up a view controller where I'm adding a bunch of `UITextField`s to my view programmatically.  I want to pre-populate the textfields with some text that I'm loading from CoreData, but allow the user to go in and change that text if they want.  I then need to go back and save that new text back to CoreData again, as well as perform calculations using the new value.  The saving and loading itself isn't a problem, but I'm looking for a good way to track what the user has changed.

In the past, I've done this with the `.tag` property of the `UITextField` and the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method.  The problem is I'm going to have dozens of textfields in this view - enough so that I can't really remember what `.tag` belongs to what variable in my model.  Having to go back to look up what tag I assigned when I created it is going to be a pain, and the whole thing feels really error prone.  Additionally, I'm going to be creating the textfields in multiple different loops, so getting a unique tag for each textfield when I create it will be difficult (maybe impossible?).

What I'm looking for is a way to "tie" the UITextField to a variable in my model when I create it and just know from that point on, whenever the user updates that textfield, the value I specify in my model will be instantly updated to be used in future calculations, and saving back to CoreData when the user leaves the screen.  Is there a way to do this?

EDIT 1: Another thing to note is that my model itself is kinda complex.  I have several different custom `NSObject` subclasses that are all holding different pieces of my data.  Some of the objects have properties that are themselves other custom objects.  I also have dictionaries where the values will be instances of some of the custom objects.

As an example, I might have these objects:

- `MySmallObject1`, which has properties `name`,`size`, and `value` (all `NSStrings`)
- `MySmallObject2`, which has properties `date` and `cost` (an `NSDate` and an `NSNumber`)
- `MyBigObject`, which has properties `box1` and `box2` (which are `MySmallObject1` and `MySmallObject2` instances, respectively)
- `theDict`, which is an `NSDictionary` instance that has `MyBigObject`s as values

So when I am building my textfields, I might actually be going down a tree that would look something like:

```
for (NSString *key in [theDict allKeys])
{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    txt.text = [[(MyBigObject *)[theDict objectForKey:key] box1] name];
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}
```

In this case, I need to know when the user changes the text in any of the `txt` and update the appropriate value through the tree.

EDIT 2: While trying to implement @Till's suggestion in the comments, I started reading a [tutorial on pointers in C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm).  It seems like this is the way I need to go, but I'm struggling to get the `&` and `*` from the C world to play nicely with the NSObject subclasses I mention in my last EDIT from the Objective-C world.  To get @Till's suggestion to work, I think I need to somehow store the memory location of my value up that complicated object tree.  So my code block from the last EDIT would become:

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *tagDict;

.m
for (NSString *key in [theDict allKeys])
{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    txt.text = [[(MyBigObject *)[theDict objectForKey:key] box1] name];
    txt.tag = globalCounter;
    [tagDict addObject:[[(MyBigObject *)[theDict objectForKey:key] box1] name] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",globalCounter]];
    globalCounter ++;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}
```

Where `globalCounter` is an `int` that I'm incrementing every time I put something into `tagDict` so I can keep it unique.  I guess in this case I could just simply be using an `NSArray` and it would work just as well, and probably look a little cleaner.  My plan is to use `tagDict` in my `testFieldDidEndEditing` like:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    *[tagDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",textField.tag]] = textField.txt;
}
```

This throws an error for `Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'NSString *'`.  I'm not really sure what that means.  Is there a way I can use a "dereferencing operator" to change the value of the item I am pointing to in my dictionary?

throws an error `Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator`.  I'm still a little fuzzy on how this pointer stuff would work in the Objective C world, and I think there's something I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: Add an abstraction layer - how about the use of a dictionary to map everything together?

Comment: @Till: I edited my OP with some more details about my model.  I think a dictionary wouldn't work in this case, because I would not be able to store the whole tree as the `key`, correct?

Comment: There are only two basic approaches that I can see: 1. use tags , 2. use instance pointers within your data model that point back to the views. 2. certainly is ugly and pure wrong in most cases. So lets check 1 a little closer... That tag could potentially be a generated value of your model. Suppose MySmallObject1 renders a unique value (lets call it Object-ID) when being asked. Now build a hash-map (aka  dictionary) that links the ID back to the object within your controller - does that make sense?

Comment: @Till: hmm, not really.  Could you elaborate a little more about what you're suggesting?  How would I get my objects to "render a unique value when being asked"?  Do you mean at runtime, when I `init` an instance of one of my objects?

Comment: It's called binding and it's not available in iOS currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing largely what I think @Till was trying to suggest.  I added an `NSMutableArray *tieArray` and an `int tieCounter` as `@properties` to my view controller.  My code for building the `UITextFields` from the first code block in my OP is now:

```
for (NSString *key in [theDict allKeys])
{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
    txt.text = [[(MyBigObject *)[theDict objectForKey:key] box1] name];
    [self.view addSubview:txt];

    txt.tag = self.tieCounter;
    self.tieCounter ++;
    [self.tieArray addObject:[[(MyBigObject *)[theDict objectForKey:key] box1] name]];
}
```

Then in my `textFieldDidEndEditing`

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([tieArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]])
    {
        [(NSMutableString *)[tieArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag] setString:textField.text];
    }
    else if (//...More conditions to set other variable types with the syntax as needed)
}
```

Note that for this to work, all the properties of `MySmallObject1` and `MySmallObject2` need to be covered by a `isKindOfClass:` check, and the actual syntax will vary a little depending on what class that property is.

I haven't been able to test this yet (and my app probably won't be in a testable state for quite some time), but it makes sense to me, and it's not throwing any errors or warnings.  If I have problems with it when I actually run it I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UITextField+blocks](https://github.com/c-rack/protocolblocks/blob/master/UIKit/UITextField+DelegateBlocks.m)  it may be less entangled. And it will be much easier if objects have similar interface or implement one protocol with method like `setText:` .

Comment: Is there any documentation with this?  I'm not used to working with blocks, so I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do with this that would help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your original approach with the .tag , but use typedefs.

```
typedef enum TFTypes {
    TFModalType1,
    TFModalType2,
    TFModalType3,
    TFModalType4,
    TFModalType5,
    ...
} TFType;
```

Comment: Using typedefs would help make the tags feel less arbitrary, but I don't think it would help with the way I have my data stored in the objects the way I describe in the edit to my OP.